# Select operation does not display characters

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 on Windows 7, the sqlite3.exe program from sqlite.org

I am using SELECT to insert arguments in a table I'm creating. One of the arguments is a specific ID from an already existing table. The ID is composed of numbers and letters; for example, 19M42DS31

My insert statement looks something like this:

```
insert into TABLE1 
values
    ((select ID
     from EMPLOYEES
     where FIRSTNAME = 'Ben' and LASTNAME = 'Smith')+'',
     ...
    );
```

However, considering 19M42DS31, sqlite3 only selects up 19 and ignores everything past 'M'. In other words, it only stores '19' which is obviously not what I want. I want the full ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT; ID is of type varchar

EDIT 2: I just tested another ID like 5987463FG32, and it actually displayed only the numbers before 'FG' (5987463) and nothing after.

Comment: Which type does `TABLE1.iD` have, maybe it's numeric?

Comment: the code bit is rather unreadable ... 
can you paste it properly, and / or show your db schema ?

Comment: What type and LENGTH are TABLE1.ID and EMPLOYEES.ID? Does EMPLOYEES actually contain the value or is it truncated already?

Comment: Employees actually contains the full value when I select it from the command line. They are both the same value, (15)

Comment: I've reformatted your SQL to our usual format for display -- just stick four spaces at the beginning of each line, or click the "code" button after you've selected code in the editor. (Please don't leave HTML markup in your SQL; it makes it harder to edit, and SO already syntax-highlights SQL) You may want to check that your SQL is still an accurate representation of the original -- you seem to have one opening bracket and two closing brackets there...

Comment: Thanks for the edit Matt! I did check, but it seems like I just missed a bracket when typing it. The problem is still there though. Isn't giving me any errors when I read it into the console, but whenever I display it it gives me '19'. What's even weirder is that, if I add more numbers in front of the letter M, it displays them. Seems like it doesn't like letters for some reason

Comment: have a look at this cool utility: [sqlite administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) . Then open your DB , and see what's there. You can also add and play with the insert command from there...

Answer (score 0):

The column should be of VARCHAR datatype

Comment: the column is of varchar type. Just edited my post. The problem is still not gone

Answer (score 0):

Having tried this, it seems to be the `+''` you've got as part of your INSERT that's causing the problem. This works:

```
insert into TABLE1 
values
    ((select ID
     from EMPLOYEES
     where FIRSTNAME = 'Ben' and LASTNAME = 'Smith')
    );
```

...where this doesn't:

```
insert into TABLE1 
    values
    ((select ID
     from EMPLOYEES
     where FIRSTNAME = 'Ben' and LASTNAME = 'Smith')+''
    );
```

(I initially just tried it without the `+''` because I couldn't really see the point of it.)

I don't know much about sqlite, I'm afraid, but if you were trying for a string concatenation, I think the operator you're looking for is `||`, not `+`. I'd *guess* the `+` is actually an arithmetic operator in sqlite, and that's why your string is being converted to a number -- probably the empty string is taken as a zero, and added to the numeric beginning of the value in the table.

(Why *is* that `+''` in there, by the way? What were you attempting to do by adding it?)